# Create a new factor based on values of two other values

Tags: r

```
dput(dta[1:4, ])
structure(list(A = c(112551L, 112551L, 112551L, 112551L), set1.RTTime = 
c(349897L, 
349897L, 349897L, 349897L), set2.RTTime = c(592639L, 592639L, 
592639L, 592639L), set3.RTTime = c(840648L, 840648L, 840648L, 
840648L), set4.RTTime = c(1082053L, 1082053L, 1082053L, 1082053L
), set5.RTTime = c(1322732L, 1322732L, 1322732L, 1322732L), set6.RTTime = 
c(1559749L, 
1559749L, 1559749L, 1559749L), set7.RTTime = c(1802346L, 1802346L, 
1802346L, 1802346L), set8.RTTime = c(2041123L, 2041123L, 2041123L, 
2041123L), set9.RTTime = c(2278899L, 2278899L, 2278899L, 2278899L
), Tokens.RESP = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), var.Block. = c(3000L, 1500L, 
1500L, 3000L)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to create a new factor which would depend on the levels of the other two factors. One factor named 'Tokens.RESP' takes on the values of A, B, C, or D per trial per subject. Another factor named 'var.Block.' can be either a negative or a positive value or zero varying on each trial (ex., a subject earns -1500 coins or 3000 coins, or earns 0 coins). I would like to create a new factor, named let's say 'condition', which would take on 6 different possible values in each trial:

1. if a subject picked A or B and earned coins, then condition 'risky_gain',
2. if a subject picked A or B and lost coins, then condition 'risky_loss',
3. if a subject picked A or B and gained 0 coins, then condition 'risky_neutral',
4. if a subject picked C or D and earned coins, then condition 'safe_gain',
5. if a subject picked C or D and lost coins, then condition 'safe_loss',
6. if a subject picked C or D and gained 0 coins, then condition 'safe_neutral'.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I can't test this without a reproducible example of your data, but you can try `factor(paste(ifelse(grepl("A|B", Tokens.Resp), "risky", "safe"), ifelse(var < 0, "loss", "gain", sep = "_")))`

Comment: That's 6 different value according to my count. Also there is not variable named `var` in your dataset. Note that `factor` has a very specific meaning in the context of R.

Answer (score 0):

For a base R approach, you could try:

```
dta$risk <- ifelse(dta$Tokens.RESP == "A" | dta$Tokens.RESP == "B", "risky", "safe")
dta$change <- ifelse(dta$var.Block. > 0, "gain", ifelse(dta$var.Block. < 0, "loss", "neutral"))
dta$condition <- factor(paste(dta$risk, dta$change, sep = "_"))
```

This includes two intermediate steps to determine risky vs. safe, and then gain/loss/neutral, and then combining these two. When you create your `factor` you can also define levels to ensure all levels are represented.

Another alternative would be `dplyr` and `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

dta %>%
  mutate(condition = factor(case_when(
    (Tokens.RESP == "A" | Tokens.RESP == "B") & var.Block. > 0 ~ "risky_gain",
    (Tokens.RESP == "A" | Tokens.RESP == "B") & var.Block. < 0 ~ "risky_loss",
    (Tokens.RESP == "A" | Tokens.RESP == "B") & var.Block. == 0 ~ "risky_neutral",
    (Tokens.RESP == "C" | Tokens.RESP == "D") & var.Block. > 0 ~ "safe_gain",
    (Tokens.RESP == "C" | Tokens.RESP == "D") & var.Block. < 0 ~ "safe_loss",
    (Tokens.RESP == "C" | Tokens.RESP == "D") & var.Block. == 0 ~ "safe_neutral"
  ), levels = c("risky_gain", "risky_loss", "risky_neutral", "safe_gain", "safe_loss", "safe_neutral")))
```

This will explicitly define each factor and level.

Or you can use `fcase` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dta)

dta[ , condition := fcase(
  (Tokens.RESP == "A" | Tokens.RESP == "B") & var.Block. > 0, "risky_gain",
  (Tokens.RESP == "A" | Tokens.RESP == "B") & var.Block. < 0, "risky_loss",
  (Tokens.RESP == "A" | Tokens.RESP == "B") & var.Block. == 0, "risky_neutral",
  (Tokens.RESP == "C" | Tokens.RESP == "D") & var.Block. > 0, "safe_gain",
  (Tokens.RESP == "C" | Tokens.RESP == "D") & var.Block. < 0, "safe_loss",
  (Tokens.RESP == "C" | Tokens.RESP == "D") & var.Block. == 0, "safe_neutral")]
```